# Mysql: set variable in mysqldump

Tags: mariadb, mysqldump, mariadb-10.2

I recently added a global variable in mmy.cnf max_statement_time=120 ; to stop long running queries and to throw an exception. Its working fine. Then I am unable to run mysqldump for backing up all my databases , obviously its true that we have large databases so backing up using mysqldump will take hours since here I have added max_statement_time to 120 seconds only. So how I can pass this as a session variable thru mysqldump to set it to hours just for mysqldump and still global value remains 120 seconds itself. Apparently I am after something like below :

```
mysqldump --max_statement_time=1000000 -u root -pMYPASS --all-databases > file.sql
```

Do we have any option there ? I went thru the mysqldump and found that it has --variable-name=value , but its not accepting this. I am using Mariadb 10.2 version.

Comment: If you create / [alter the root user](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/grant/) with a large `MAX_STATEMENT_TIME` does that take precedence over the global variable? Otherwise a [creating a feature task](https://jira.mariadb.org) of `--dump-variable=value` seems like sane feature request.

Comment: @danblack Hey could u please tell me how to alter the root user with max_statement_time ?  So I could try that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to specify a session variable by placing it in a `backup.cnf` file:

```
max_statement_time=10000
```

And then using the `--defaults-file=backup.cnf` parameter to `mysqldump`.

(You can also place user credentials in that file so that you don't have to show the username and password on the command-line, which is a potential security issue.)

Comment: The config is not part of the `[mysqldump]` command line option. But you have to put in the daemon section `[mysqld]`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a new user just for dumping.  Give it `SUPER` privilege so that it can do what it needs.  And also give it unlimited `max_execution_time`.

Then you don't need an extra parameter in the places you were guessing about.

Comment: Would u givem me the query to create a backup user as u specified with grant option to have max_execution_time, please.

Comment: @SAGARNair - To modify an existing user's `MAX_STATEMENT_TIME` do `ALTER USER testuser@localhost WITH MAX_STATEMENT_TIME 10;`. Or alternatively: `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO testuser@localhost WITH MAX_STATEMENT_TIME 10;` 

To create a new user, do: `CREATE USER testuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'the password' WITH MAX_STATEMENT_TIME 10;`